# Unzip and save files using as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, zip

I have a list of zip and rar files in a local folder.
All I need to do is to extract the contents of the zip as well as rar files and to save them in a folder with the same name of the respective archive file.
Since I am new to as3, I have no clue for this.
Is there any Library for this???
 
 
 
 
 Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can't do local file operations without using AIR or something like it. If you are developing a local application, my advice to you is try to write those parts with a more powerful language like c++. But there is also something like this http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few libraries out there that deal with ZIP files in as3, but beware that this is no easy task for a beginner in ActionScript 3.

- [FZip](https://github.com/claus/fzip/) seems to be the most widely used, but it requires that the ZIP archives have **Adler32 checksums**. Provided with the library there is a Python script that injects the checksum into ZIP files to preprocess the files before unzipping them.
- [As3 port of JZlib](http://www.wirelust.com/2009/06/08/as3-port-of-jzlib/), an as3 library to use with **Fzip** instead of the Python script mentioned above.
- [AS3 Zip Library](http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15) (the author states that is slower than **FZip**) that avoids the **Addler32 checksum problem**.
- On **Adobe Air**, you can take a look at a detailed explanation and a working example in [this article on the adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/compressing_files.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: For the record, since Flash Player 10 (i.e., long time ago) FZip does *not* require checksum injection anymore. It just works.

Answer (score 10):

To decompress zip files, you can use **[AS3Commons Zip](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-zip/index.html)** (formerly know as FZip). It works **without** the Adler32 checksum requirement mentionned in a previous answer.

Here's an example of how to extract all files in a zip archive. The function below would be called when a `URLLoader` object has downloaded the zip file and dispatched an `Event.COMPLETE` event:

```
import org.as3commons.zip.Zip;
import org.as3commons.zip.ZipFile;

private function _onZipDownloaded(e:Event):void {

    var ba:ByteArray = ByteArray(e.target.data);
    var zip:Zip = new Zip();
    zip.loadBytes(ba);

    for(var i:uint = 0; i < zip.getFileCount(); i++) {

        var zipFile:ZipFile = zip.getFileAt(i);
        var extracted:File = directory.resolvePath(zipFile.filename);

        var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
        fs.open(extracted, FileMode.WRITE);
        fs.writeBytes(zipFile.content);
        fs.close();

    }

}
```

Obviously, error checking should be added to the code above but you get the idea...