# Flex: Zip multiple images in to one folder and save on disk

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

Right now I can save only one image using `filereference`.
 Is there a way to save multiple images from array collection into a zip folder?

**Code:**

```
var originalImage:UploadedImage = listOfSelectedImages.getItemAt(0) as UploadedImage;
var resizedData:BitmapData = scaleBitmap(originalImage.imageBitmap.bitmapData, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
var encoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
var byteArray:ByteArray = encoder.encode(resizedData);
fileReference.save(byteArray,"1.jpeg");
```

Comment: Doesnt [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907513/unzip-and-save-files-using-as3) help?

Comment: Write a script in your favorite server-side language, for example PHP, that accepts a list of files and returns a link to the zip folder. Call this script from Flex

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Coltware AirxZip or [AS3-Commons](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-zip/asdoc/index.html) to extract and create zips.