# How to extract files XML, Json in bytearray in AS3

Tags: xml, json, actionscript-3, flash

How to extract files XML, JSON in bytearray in AS3 when uncompress. Or edit string in bytearray.

I want translate language in a game from China into English

```
package  {

import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import com.hurlant.util.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.utils.*;
import spark.components.*;
import valueObjects.*;

public class Tools extends MovieClip {
    public var fileStream:FileStream;
    public var frdataObj:Object;
    public function Tools() {
        // constructor code
        this.fileStream = new FileStream();
        trace("Test Okie!");
        var _loc_7:File = null;
        var _loc_8:FileStream = null;
        var _loc_3:ByteArray = null;
        var _loc_2:* = new File(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("data").nativePath);
        if (_loc_2.exists)
        {
            this.fileStream.open(_loc_2, FileMode.READ);
            _loc_3 = new ByteArray();
            this.fileStream.readBytes(_loc_3);
            this.fileStream.close();
            _loc_3.uncompress();
            this.frdataObj = _loc_3.readObject();
            var _loc_4:* = undefined;

        //trace(ohterXML);

       for (_loc_4 in this.frdataObj)
       {

            trace(this.frdataObj[_loc_4]);
        }
            _loc_7 = new File(File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("config23.txt").nativePath);
        _loc_8 = new FileStream();
        _loc_8.open(_loc_7, FileMode.WRITE);
        _loc_8.writeObject(frdataObj);
        _loc_8.close();
        }
    }
} 
}
```

Result trace from Bytearray uncompress

https://i.stack.imgur.com/McutO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This example would work even with Flash, not only Air.

I made it as an Document Class for Flash, but of course it can be recreated as you wish.

So calling saveData(); brings up Save Dialog and you can save zipped binary file (just put it in the app directory), on the next run you can just comment //saveData()  and call loadData(); (as it is now) and you'll get XML as the result.

```
package
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{

    public function Main()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event):void
    {
        //saveData (); //use for saving zipped binary XML, or any String
        loadData(); //use for loading and unzipping binary XML or any String

    }

    private function saveData():void
    {

        var xmlData:String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><data>some data here</data>';
        var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        data.writeUTFBytes(xmlData);
        data.compress();
        new FileReference().save(data, "binaryData.xml");
    }

    private function loadData():void
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("binaryData.xml");
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        loader.load(request);
    }

    private function completeHandler(e:Event):void
    {
        var data:ByteArray = e.currentTarget.data;
        data.uncompress();
        trace(data.toString());
        var xmlData:XML = XML(data); //and this is XML from the file
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: There are many xml files in Binary Data ... So, how ! Thanks for help me

Comment: Link file BinaryData : https://mega.co.nz/#!pINAxRoA!UjGBJMQOIe-2_IWtX_NROdTrKMhXeK1Z5d6UNlGPfnU

PLease help me

Comment: File you gave isn't Zip, anyway if you want to work with ZIP files instead of just Zipped String check this library http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-zip/ and look here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907513/unzip-and-save-files-using-as3