# Unzip files on a PC?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, zip

Is it possible to:

- download a zip file with assets
- unzip those assets
- use them

In a PC?, not mobile?.

Read somewhere that is not possible to do so on a PC (only on mobile), but I can't find any article backing it up.

Comment: If you are talking Browser-based flash, you can do it as long as you never want to automatically saved them to the local hard drive. Using a in-memory only process, you can use the ByteArray `inflate` in Flash you can byte- fiddle each 'file' in the zip into a separate asset. Google is your friend in finding src...  IMHO: It is easier just to http/https stream the actual asset in terms of client processing time vs. download speed...

Comment: Yeah I meant a Air project for PC, not web.

Comment: You can do it on PC/MAC/Mobile.   See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21562718/1457439

Comment: @Artemix FYI: Adobe has example source on their site for Air-based unzip

Comment: AIR desktop is np working with zip files.