# Saving an image to local disk in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs6, flash-cc

I have a rectangle MovieClip (named rect) on the stage and i want the user to be able to save that rectangle MovieClip as a ".png" image on  his computer, this is what  i did:

```
//Convert my MovieClip to BitmapData
var bitmapData:BitmapData=new BitmapData(rect.width, rect.height);

//Create new ByteArray
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

//Encode my Bitmap to PNG
bitmapData.encode(new Rectangle(0,0,450,170), new flash.display.PNGEncoderOptions(), byteArray);

//saving the byteArray that holds the PNG as "myimage.png"
var fileReference:FileReference=new FileReference();
fileReference.save(byteArray, "myimage.png");
```

when i run the code, it prompts the windows save dialogue and when i save the image i get a blank ".png" image named "myimage.png" with size 450x170 that i specified. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You forgot to **bitmapData.draw(rect);** before encoding.

Comment: Yes, Thanks i just figured it out. The problem that i have now is that i want the user to save ten MovieClips instantaneously, without the hassle of saving each one alone. the MovieClips are on the stage and i made a Download button, if clicked, then it should save all the 10 MovieClips to his computer, any idea?

Comment: You cannot batch things like that, the security restrictions (as long as your app is a web app) dictates to save files individually.

Comment: As an idea, if that will do for you, you can ZIP as many files as you want into one archive and save the archive.

Comment: That's a good idea, but how can i zip the MovieClips after they've been encoded and then download them collectively?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907513/unzip-and-save-files-using-as3

Comment: You should probably make a new question since you've already solved your original problem.